# ScrollView content offset freezes compass

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, compass

There is a scrollView on the screen, under it is a compass arrow. As soon as I move the contents of the scrollView up or down the screen, the compass stops working. When I release the scrollView, the compass is restored.
When I rotate the compass arrow by changing the variable on the timer, shifting the contents of the scrollView does not affect this process.
How to fix it?

```
import SwiftUI

import Foundation
import Combine
import CoreLocation

class CompassHeading: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
var degrees: Double = .zero {
    didSet {
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}

private let locationManager: CLLocationManager

override init() {
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    super.init()
    
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.setup()
}

private func setup() {
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    
    if CLLocationManager.headingAvailable() {
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    self.degrees = -1 * newHeading.magneticHeading
}
}

struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var compassHeading = CompassHeading()

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Some words\nSome words\nSome words\n")
                .padding()
        }
        
        Text("⬆️")
            .font(.system(size: 100))
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: compassHeading.degrees))
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Why have you defined your own objectWillChange?

Comment: Also, you should be using StateObject, not ObservedObject

Comment: I changed  ObservedObject to StateObject and made var degrees @Published, nothing has changed in the behavior of the program